# The 'Other Data Source' button is not activated when creating a SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql-server-2016

[image]

- RDBMS: SQL Server 2016 Standard edition
- OS : Windows server 2016 Standard
- Tool : SSMS 18.12.1 ( English )

I am attempting to establish a linked server connection with a server on a different IP address. However, the 'Other Data Source' button is disabled.

- Creating through `sp_addlinkedserver` is possible without issues
- I tried logging in with Windows authentication and SQL Server authentication, but the same problem occurred
- I restarted SQL Server, but the same problem occurred

Comment: I have never had ths problem, but have you checked you have any appropriate drivers installed. When I look in the Provider combo box, the provider I use is 'Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server'. You could try installing this and see if the option becomes available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16